# Emacs: How to define and initialize a custom variable in the .emacs file

Tags: emacs, initialization

I think my emacs may not read the ~/.emacs initialization file. I'd like to put this theory to the test. Any suggestions will be welcome. However, I have come up with the following idea.

Suppose I define and initialize a custom boolean variable in the ~/.emacs file. I can then check this variable's value once emacs opens, by issuing the command `C-h v <custom variable name> RET`.

So my question is: how can I define and initialize a custom boolean variable in my init file? Is it by adding the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
(setq <custom variable name> t)
```

I should add that the following empty parentheses appear at the beginning of my init file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: You may want to check out the new Emacs.SE site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(setq <custom variable name> t)` approach will work fine. Alternatively, you could simply emit a message in your `.emacs`:

```
(message "successfully loaded .emacs")
```

and then check the `*Messages*` buffer to make sure the message is there.